# What is the maximum volume of an upside down cone inscribed inside a hemisphere.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry, optimization, maxima-minima

I Tried letting the radius of the cone be "$r$" and the height "$h$" and then the radius of the hemisphere "$R$" is $\sqrt{(r²+h²)}$.

I tried letting an angle $\theta$ and tried to simplify things down, and taking the derivative, but it just isn't working, is there some other nice approach because I am not finding a similar problem anywhere on the internet - I mean, it seemed a little too trivial to me at first, but since the cone is inverted so I just couldn't let $R=h$ and substitute the values in, and the cone is also in a hemisphere not a sphere, so I couldn't really figure out what to do.

An explanation would be very much appreciated.

Comment: $R$ is fixed and you can express $r$ in terms of $R$ and $h$.  Once you do that, it's a straightforward maximization problem in one variable ($h$).

Comment: Look at this 2d version: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0ltgiymi4g It's actually the middle intersection of the 3d problem and has all the needed information, just maximize the function $V(h)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to maximum the volume

$V = \frac{1}{3} r^2 h $

where $r, h$ satisfy

$ r^2 + h^2 = R^2 $

and $R$ is the radius of the sphere.

From this, you can write $r^2 = R^2 - h^2$ and substitute in the volume function

$ V = \frac{1}{3} h (R^2 - h^2) $

Now differentiate with respect to $h$,

$ \dfrac{dV}{dh} = \frac{1}{3} ( R^2 - h^2 - 2 h^2 ) = \frac{1}{3} (R^2 - 3 h^2) $

The second derivative is  $ \dfrac{d^2 V}{d h^2} = -2 h $

Setting $\dfrac{dV}{dh} = 0 $ gives us,

$ h^2 = \frac{1}{3} R^2 $

So that

$ h = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} R $

To check that this actually a maximum, substitute into the expression of the second derivative, you'll get a negative value, indicating that it is a maximum.